# IDX12723: Unable to decode the payload '[PII of type 'System.String' is hidden

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, .net-8.0

After I upgrade my project to .NET 8 from .NET 6, I faced this error:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'IDX12723: Unable to decode the payload '[PII of type 'System.String' is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]' as Base64Url encoded string.'
Inner Exception
JsonException: IDX11020: The JSON value of type: 'String', could not be converted to 'JsonTokenType.Number'. Reading: 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtPayload.iat', Position: '52', CurrentDepth: '1', BytesConsumed: '82'.
```

I tried many ways but I can not solve it. The error appreared when go here:

```
var token = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"].FirstOrDefault()?.Split(" ")[1];
var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var authToken = tokenHandler.ReadToken(token) as JwtSecurityToken; // <=== ERROR HERE
```

Please help me! Thank you so much!

Comment: What is the value of `JwtPayload.iat`? How is it set?

Comment: I set it is `DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString()`

Comment: Check out the answer, it should be a number (usually Unix time I assume). Something like `DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> JsonException: IDX11020: The JSON value of type: 'String', could not be converted to 'JsonTokenType.Number'. Reading: 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtPayload.iat', Position: '52', CurrentDepth: '1', BytesConsumed: '82'.

See [this comment](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/52191#issuecomment-1817856054) to [this issue @github](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/52191):

> Based on the [RFC 7519](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519#section-4.1.6) this claim MUST be number.

The JWT that you are sending in the request has `iat` claim as string and the later version of the library is stricter about this. Without seeing the actual value (and how you are getting it) you can try:

- Setting [`JsonSerializerOptions.JsonNumberHandling`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonnumberhandling?view=net-8.0) to `AllowReadingFromString` (though I would guess it likely will not help).
- Downgrading to [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer` 7.0.14](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer/7.0.14)
- Checking the code - maybe you are setting this JWT prop to incorrect value somewhere

**UPD**

Based on the comments the last option applied - explicit `DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString()` value was set to `JwtPayload.iat` header. `DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds()` was suggested as substitution, another option is `EpochTime.GetIntDate(DateTime)` (see [this comment](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/52191#issuecomment-1825686028)).