# Updating to .net 8 breaks Bearer Token authorization

Tags: .net-8.0

My implementation was working fine until updating to .net 8.
Now I just get 401s.

Have tried all the answers to related SO questions to no avail

Comment: Please check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77641054/2501279). There is a chance you have the same problem.

Comment: .NET 8 has big breaking changes, so authorization has changed and this is expected behaviour when updating from 7 to 8.

Answer (score 0):

I reverted the library `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer` back to 7.0.4 and that has fixed it.

8.0.0 just doesn't work lol.

Comment: "8.0.0 just doesn't work lol." - quite a bold statement =)

Comment: Same here... I checked the token and is not a string vs number problem (my token has a number for `iat` value) like suggested in the linked answer... Seems reverting is the only way atm.